# How should a dotnet core command line application be installed on a Linux system

Tags: linux, .net-core

I'm maintaining a couple of .NET applications on GitHub. I've been getting requests to port them over to .NET Core so that they can be used on Linux systems. I would like to make the Linux users' life easy by providing some sort of package like NuGet that can be installed.

However I'm not aware of any conventions for where the executable files actually should live in the file system. Ideally, the binaries will be deployed in directories on the `PATH`, but I'm not sure what convetions dotnet Core uses when it comes to the physical locations of .NET assemblies.

Ideally, I'd like to deploy:

- The main assembly, `pytocs.dll`
- A shell script that asks the dotnet core executive to launch the tool:

```
#!/bin/bash
dotnet pytocs.dll "$@"
```

but I don't know where those two file should go.

Comment: “I would like to make the Linux users' life easy by providing some sort of package like NuGet that can be installed.” What's that? Only if you decide to ship a Global Tool for .NET Core SDK users NuGet packages might be used as the delivery method. In all other cases, you should ship a Zip package (portable build to run), or pack up as standard Linux package (RPM for instance). Please try not to ask your end users to install .NET Core runtime on their own (like `dotnet` you showed as example), and use self-contained deployment instead.

Comment: BTW, you might find this more convenient, https://www.hanselman.com/blog/BrainstormingCreatingASmallSingleSelfcontainedExecutableOutOfANETCoreApplication.aspx

Comment: I can make an RPM package or an APT package, but where should the files actually go? Should the shell script be dumped in `/usr/bin`? Where does the .NET Core `.dll` file go?